# Equation does not compile

Tags: amsmath

The equation above is giving errors such as `Undefined control sequence`, `Missing number, treated as zero`, `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\begin {document}

\begin {equation}
\gamma_{\alpha , \beta} = \int \int' \Gamma [\vec{r},\vec{r}',n_0] \frac {F^{\alpha}_{00}(|\vec{r} - \vec{R_{\alpha} | ) F^{\beta}_{00}(|\vec{r}' - \vec{R_{\beta}} | ) } }{4\pi}
\end {equation}

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have mismatch with curly braces ... try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\alpha , \beta} =
    \int \int' \Gamma [\vec{r},\vec{r'},n_0]
\frac{F^{\alpha}_{00}(|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_{\alpha}|)F^{\beta}_{00}(|\vec{r'}-\vec{R_{\beta}}|)}
     {4\pi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\gamma_{\alpha , \beta} =
    \int \int' \Gamma [\vec{r},\vec{r}\,',n_0]
\frac{F^{\alpha}_{00}(|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_{\alpha}|)F^{\beta}_{00}(|\vec{r}\,'-\vec{R_{\beta}}|)}
        {4\pi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would have better to split your equation

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage {amsmath}%
\begin {document}%
%
\newcommand{\leftmember}{\gamma_{\alpha , \beta}}%
\newcommand{\numerator}{\utilityF{\alpha} \utilityF{\beta} }%
\newcommand{\utilityF}[1]{F^{#1}_{00}(|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_#1|)}%
% easier to manage and improve when splitted
% for instance :
% \newcommand{\utilityF}[1]{F^{#1}_{00}\left(\left|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_#1\right|\right)}%
%
\begin{equation}
  \leftmember = \int \int' \Gamma [\vec{r},\vec{r}',n_0] \frac{\numerator} {4\pi}
\end{equation}
%
\end{document}
```